# r- grepl to find matching strings in any order

Tags: r, regex, grepl

I have a matching string . Need to find text that matches multiple string (both/all) and any order:

`Text1 : "I have no intention to make illegal parking along the road or cause obstruction."`

`Text2 : "I have no intention to make illegal parking along the road or cause damage."`

MyCode:

```
    mynames=c("illegal parking" , "obstruction")
grepl(paste(mynames, collapse='|'), Text1, ignore.case=TRUE)
```

When i pass `Text1` and `Text2` - i get `TRUE` - for Both;
However i need `TRUE` for `Text1`  and `FALSE` for `Text2` . It should result when only both strings are present - and it can be in any order with in the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`|`in regex means "or". That's why it is TRUE on both texts.
You have to test if `"illegal parking"` is followed (with or without something in between) by `"obstruction"`, in regex this is `"illegal parking.*obstruction"`, or if you have it the other way around, so `"illegal parking.*obstruction|obstruction.*illegal parking"`

```
grepl("illegal parking.*obstruction|obstruction.*illegal parking", Text1, ignore.case=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could test the results of `str_extract_all()` to see if both are matched.  This approach means you don't have to worry about the order.

```
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

map_lgl(str_extract_all(c(Text1, Text2), paste(mynames, collapse='|')), ~all(mynames %in% .x))

[1] TRUE FALSE
```